# How to return a class type with a generic in it from Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object with a specific key and a value with an array of strings.

```
const experimentPossibleVariants = {
    'experimentOne': ['experimentOne - A', 'experimentOne - B', 'experimentOne - C'],
    'experimentTwo': ['experimentTwo - A', 'experimentTwo - B', 'experimentTwo - C']
} as const;
```

I created classes to store and retrieve experiments. But there is an issue with the `return`. Because it is a bit complicated to explain, I made a typescript playground example.

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=1#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-YDmBS5rqg9D5pg94wAAVH%20%206AcBDBrhQYBgsuM6-AuAbnsGoYkjGjAppW6DVqodoMI%20tT4s0%20JttCnbdr2MFMdaAD8LFGGqc4ptC6AdAO-EQGJ77mjAwgkAAViyUBrkoGBwBA0kqrJEH9pU1DAEuA4DtI-HcmKk7TuCThzkwb4Kc5tbgKKUwbAmsYHNZxxxjkVGTvsp4udwe7rjJa5phApliL4gXJAOHleVZ-G2WCM4ziFCkZDO8lcAG-rFNCaYZlmoJgOyqyIOslXRkFSZDo0pYPgltQwAAPjA7yVXAFVwBs87OZ%2036-uFGl6RB6CVbpMbMGc-EbnGTAra0jRZaRgadmKzRxW1Rg6TJ0qyvKCobew-BTTNno6mIPAzkB6K4Mwq18DwQA) or check out all code below:

```
const experimentPossibleVariants = {
    'experimentOne': ['experimentOne - A', 'experimentOne - B', 'experimentOne - C'],
    'experimentTwo': ['experimentTwo - A', 'experimentTwo - B', 'experimentTwo - C']
} as const;

type ExperimentKey = keyof typeof experimentPossibleVariants;
type ExperimentVariant<T extends ExperimentKey = ExperimentKey> = typeof experimentPossibleVariants[T][number];
type ExperimentConfig = {
    id: number;
    variants: ExperimentVariant[]
}
type ExperimentMap = Partial<Record<ExperimentKey,ExperimentConfig>>

const experimentsFromAPI: ExperimentMap = {
    'experimentOne': {
        id: 1,
        variants: ['experimentOne - A', 'experimentOne - B', 'experimentOne - C']
    }
}

class Experiment<T extends ExperimentKey = ExperimentKey> {
    public readonly key: T;
    private config: ExperimentConfig;

    constructor(key: T, config: ExperimentConfig) {
        this.key = key;
        this.config = config;
    }

    get variant(): ExperimentVariant<T> {
        return this.config.variants[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.config.variants.length)];
    }
}

class Experiments {
    private experiments: Experiment[] = [];

    constructor(experiments?: ExperimentMap) {
        if(experiments) {
            Object.entries(experiments).forEach(([experimentKey, experimentConfig]) => {
                const typedExperimentKey = experimentKey as ExperimentKey;
                this.experiments.push(new Experiment(typedExperimentKey, experimentConfig));
            })
        }
    }

    public find<T extends ExperimentKey>(key: T): Experiment | undefined {
        return this.experiments.find(experiment => experiment.key === key);
    }
}

const exp = new Experiments(experimentsFromAPI);

exp.find('experimentOne').variant === 'e'
```

My question is why the return type of `Experiment<T>` isn't valid. It is giving me the correct results. When I use only `Experiment` as return type it says the `return` is valid, but then I get the wrong suggestions from typescript.

[image: Wrong return type]

***The upper image gives me an error for the `return`. The image below doesn't, but is giving the wrong result.***

[image: Wrong result]

What should I do to fix this so there is no error and my result is correct?

Comment: [Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/2887218). Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.  Also, screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: I get it! I'll inlcude the code. The images are just to point out where the error occurs! Is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript isn't *quite* smart enough (yet?) to automatically determine that the callback function you provide to `this.experiments.find(...)` narrows the type from `Experiment<ExperimentKey>` to `Experiment<T>`. So, you will need to help TypeScript by giving it a bit of a hint.

Specifically, you can annotate that the return value of the callback is a boolean value that declares whether the input parameter is `Experiment<T>` or not:

```
    public find<T extends ExperimentKey>(key: T): Experiment<T> | undefined {
        return this.experiments.find(
            (experiment): experiment is Experiment<T> => experiment.key === key);
    }
```

Comment: Already thought it has something to do with Typescript haha! Thank you for your answer. Didn't know about the 'is', so learned something new.